# How to implement the "Bezier approximation method" in Java programming language?

Tags: java, numerical-methods

I have to implement Bezier approximation method into Java programming language by using the next input variables:

x [0, 3.3, 6.6, 9.9]
y(x) [2.1, 5.9, 2.4, 3.4]

Would really appreciate any resources and help in general about

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe do some research about how the Bezier curves are defined...